# Operações em lista (estática) c++

Tags: c++, algoritmo, lista, struct, estrutura-de-dados

Boa tarde galera, eu tô com dificuldades para entender as operações em listas estaticas, eu sei criar e exibir, mas como eu faço para remover e busca dentro da lista, os algoritmos de ordenação eu já entendi alguns, podem me ajudar, por favor? Eu tô meio desesperado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> //lib pra poder usar o strcpy
#define maximo 2
using namespace std;

struct pessoa {
  char nome [20];
  int idade;
  float altura;
  float peso;
};

void imprime (pessoa alguem[]){
  for (int i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
    cout <<"Nome: "<< alguem[i].nome << " - ";
    cout <<"Idade: "<<alguem[i].idade << " - ";
    cout <<"Altura: " << alguem[i].altura << " - ";
    cout <<"Peso: "<< alguem[i].peso<< "\n";

  }
}
int main() {

pessoa alguem [maximo];

for (int i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
  cout << "Insira o nome: " << '\n';
  cin >> alguem[i].nome;
  cout << "Insira a idade: " << '\n';
  cin >> alguem[i].idade;
  cout << "Insira a altura: " << '\n';
  cin >> alguem[i].altura;
  cout << "Insira o peso: " << '\n';
  cin >> alguem[i].peso;
}
  imprime (alguem);
}
```

Comment: Existe algum motivo para usar C em um código que supostamente deveria ser C++? A busca é quase igual à impressão, só que faz uma comparação pra ver se o item é o que está buscando. A remoção é bem mais complicada, começa buscando o que deseja remover, a não ser que se saiba a posição dele. Aí terá que puxar cada item para o anterior desde o item que foi removido, e não esquece de limpar o último. É claro que tem como usar coisas prontas que faz tudo por você.

Comment: Você poderia melhorar a sua pergunta. O que você quer saber exatamente? O seu código faz um loop de tamanho fixo para adicionar dentro de um array instâncias do struct pessoa, e depois usa um loop equivalente para imprimir o que foi inserido. Agora você quer buscar um elemento específico do array, e também remover um elemento específico?

Comment: @rafaelB. O meu problema é que eu preciso, de alguma forma excluir uma instância do struct que já foi posta na lista, só que eu não estou conseguindo desenvolver a lógica para tal.

Comment: Use std::vector ou std::deque com ambos você pode excluir um elemento desde que saiba qual a posição dele, a posição de todos próximos elementos serão reajustadas automaticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sugestão mais prática de ser implementada é a que o @Nex' e o @Maniero falaram: use as estruturas já prontas do C++ ([vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/), etc). Elas já vem com métodos próprios de busca, inserção e remoção já otimizados.

Se realmente for necessário usar array, você pode tentar a seguinte abordagem:

**Utilizar vetor de ponteiros**

Acho que fica mais fácil de encontrar os elementos já removidos/fim da lista.

```
pessoa* alguem[maximo];

for (int i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
    alguem[i] = new pessoa;
    //...
}
```

**Escolher um campo para fazer a busca**

Para fazer uma busca, você tem que designar algum campo para achar o elemento (índice, nome, etc).

```
void busca(pessoa* alguem[], int idade) {
for (int i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
    if (alguem[i] != NULL && alguem[i]->idade == idade) {
        //Achou e pára a busca
    }
}
//Não achou
}
```

**Escolher um campo para fazer a busca e remover**

Aqui você pode seguir a mesma lógica da busca para achar o elemento a ser removido. Aí você pode ou simplesmente apontar o índice do vetor para nulo (mais simples), redimensionar o vetor ou criar um vetor novo com tamanho *n-1*, onde *n* é o tamanho atual do vetor. Poderia algo do gênero:

```
    //Removendo o elemento fazendo com que o índice aponte para nulo
void remove(pessoa* alguem[], int idade) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
        if (alguem[i] != NULL && alguem[i]->idade == idade) {
            alguem[i] = NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```